# Can't reproduce payment instrument token creation action from sandbox with "Invalid profile owner" error

Tags: cybersource

I want to create a token for card with given API call https://developer.cybersource.com/api-reference-assets/index.html#token-management_payment-instrument_create-a-payment-instrument as CyberSource's Intro video suggests. With default credentials that sandbox provide(testrest merchant) everything goes fine but when I use my credentials generated in https://ebc2test.cybersource.com I am always getting next error(I don't edit initial request that sandbox provides; with this exact request and default credentials CyberSource generates token and successfully returns it to API test page)

```
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "type": "forbidden",
            "message": "Invalid profile owner"
        }
    ]
}
```

I have tried to use merchant API shared key/secret as well as user-specific credentials from the same merchant profile.

What I did wrong(may be I need to change smth in merchant profile) and what I need to do to make it work ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We had the same problem. It was related to the profileId. The hard coded profile id isn't valid. You need to get your own profile id from customer support. From what I gather the profile id is used to reference your specific tokens. It's a discount double check if you will that the tokens you are inputting are connected to your account.

Comment: Yeah, I already trying to obtain it but unsuccessfully. According to this page https://support.cybersource.com/s/article/How-Do-I-Contact-CyberSource-Customer-Support I contacted support via "live chat" in my test merchant profile. But it's happened to be sales department... and they just answered with some vague phrases with advice to contact billing dept, though it doesn't seem reasonable for technical question as I can understand. May I ask which contact channel did you used to get profile-id?

Comment: Yes.  I will message it to you off line for reasons you will understand when you read my message. :-) EDIT: Yay. Apparently I can't PM users on here. I'm new to Stack. Try: 855-477-1185 it's enterprise support, play dumb and beg.  You should get it resolved.

Answer (score 0):

The profile id within a REST API context is assigned by CyberSource within the Gateway account and with TMS is a specific id for your TOKEN MANAGEMENT collection.

Comment: sorry i came late to party, But where is this profile ? i can't find it in 2020? contacted their developers via email and they only replied that it's not required anymore! I am using their Rest API and it still requires it!!!